# Why doesn't relative humidity tend to 100%?

Tags: physical-chemistry, vapor-pressure

Relative humidity is defined as:
$$\frac{\text{pressure of $\ce{H2O}$  vapours}}{\text{vapour pressure of $\ce{H2O}$ at that temperature}} \times 100$$

Suppose the temperature is fixed and  I apply Le Chatalier's principle, then would relative humidity always try to be 100%?

Comment: Temperature and pressure are not fixed in the atmosphere. Infinite water is not usually available to try and saturate the air. Yes, water evaporates to try and hit high relative humidity, but the system is much more complex.

Comment: Sure, it always tries to be 100%, but rarely succeeds.

Answer (score 2):

If atmospheric air masses had had constant temperature, the relative humidity would have converged to 100%.

But, because of dynamic nature of atmosphere behavior, there are processes of cooling down and warming up of air. The former eventually leads to water condensation and precipitation, while the latter leads to decreased relative humidity, compared to the initial conditions.

By other words, with all that raining and snowing, how one could expect atmosphere in the whole can ever get saturated ?

---

(The user served as an enlisted airfield meteorologist of the Czechoslovak army in 1989-90)